# Posting user input to web form via Python

Tags: python, forms

I have a web form that I would like to be filled out via users through a python bot. Everything that I can find regarding this pulls all of the data from a pre-defined payload via request or mechanize, however my situation differs in that I'd like users to be able to trigger this with their own text (for example - .submit Ticket #1234 - Blah blah blah).

The page they are submitting to is a simple form - 1 text area and 1 submit button.

Could anyone shine some light on some tutorials or how I'd go about this?

Here's my attempt:

```
import re
import urllib.parse
import requests

from lxml import etree

@hook.command("addquote")
def addquote(text, bot):
    """<query> -- adds a quote to the qdb."""
    url = 'example.com/?add';
    values = {'addquote' : text}
    data = urllib.urlencode(values)
    req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    the_page = response.read()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide a more detailed example? It is also important to show what you have tried and where did you get stuck.

Comment: I've tried doing a general post, but I'm sure I'm doing it wrong. Here's the code I've tried:

`import re
import urllib.parse

import requests
from lxml import etree

@hook.command("addquote")
def addquote(text, bot):
    """<query> -- adds a quote to the qdb."""
    url = 'http://example.com/?add'
    values = {'addquote' : text}
    data = urllib.urlencode(values)
    req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req) 
    the_page = response.read()
`
Basically what I want is to have a trigger with some text to be passed to the form and submitted.

Comment: replace the last 3 line with `f = urllib.urlopen(url, data)` and `the_page = f.read()`

Comment: Didn't understood your question. Can you please elaborate ? Do you want something like a program that enters all the value of the form and submit it on it's own without clicking the submit button ? If yes then you should take a look at `Selenium` . Or do you want to send a request to a url using `GET` or `POST` method with predefined values ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using HTTP POST. If your web form uses PUT just change the method. It outputs the page that is returned (which probably isn't needed unless you want to check for success) and the HTTP status code and reason. This is Python 3, only small changes are needed for older versions:

```
import urllib.parse, urllib.request
url="http://hskhsk.pythonanywhere.com/cidian"
params={"q":"apple","secondparam":"ignored"}
encoded=urllib.parse.urlencode(params) 
data=bytes(encoded, 'utf-8')
req = urllib.request.Request(url=url, data=data, method="POST")
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as f:
    print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
print(f.status)
print(f.reason)
```

The web form that it calls is a simple English-Chinese dictionary that accepts HTTP GET or POST requests. The text to search for (apple) is the `q` parameter and the other parameter is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading this book http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex51.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple example, using Grablib:

```
# we will use GrabLib (http://docs.grablib.org/en/latest/)
from grab import Grab
g = Grab()

g.go ('someurl.com')

g.set_input ('form name', 'text to be inputted')
g.submit
```

Thats all)